# Is there a way to quickly bookmark files in W10?

Tags: windows-10, bookmarks, selection

I have to choose some 10 pics from a folder containing some 4000 pics. Is there a way I can quickly bookmark those I like, as to narrow the selection? I use W10.

Comment: Create a new temp folder, open one Explorer window for your photo foler in the huge thumbnail mode, another for the temp folder, put the two side by side, and then drag each photo you like to the temp folder. You can do this gain to narrow the search. You can keep the temp folder and rename it to "Liked".

Comment: Or just right-click and drag, choosing to create a shortcut in the new folder.